# Extracting screen time usage of the user in an Ios app (maybe with the Screen Time API)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Dear StackOverFlow Friends,

We are having a hard time understanding a concept that relates to the app idea that we are planning to develop. Imagine that we have an app called A. that requires the user's screen time usage information for selected apps like Udemy, Duolingo, and such. Our concept does not require any kind of app tracking or anything else, the only information that we need to acquire is the screen time information of the user. Accordingly, we have found an API namely Screen Time API, however, within the documentations and open topics, we couldn’t exactly be sure that we would be allowed to have such information. In this sense, we will need your kind support directing us around the idea and API.

The app will provide a futuristic, ToDo, and agile-oriented device usage environment for users to track their daily objectives by directly using the screen time information (of the apps, not just the overall phone usage).

- Are we able to extract Screen Time information of the user's various apps?
- Are we able to use the Screen Time API, no questions asked?
- Do we need to create a proposal for the AppStore team that elaborates our idea for the App publishment?

Regards.

Comment: Ask one question at a time, s'il vous plait.

Comment: If you have any of the answers, then please share only one my kind friend

Comment: 1. No.  The Screen Time API allows you to set limits on the time an app or apps can be used during scheduled hours but does not report how much time was actually used.  Your app receives an event if the limit is reached.  2. Any app can use the Screen Time API.  The Screen Time API can only be used in the context of an Apple ID family and allows a family "parent" to set policies for devices linked to a "child" account in the family.  The app on the child device needs to receive approval before it can implement controls.  3. No. See 2.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10123/

Comment: There is an update to this API in 2022. (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/)
But I still don't understand if it is possible to access the raw usage data to do some calculations. If you find a more detailed documentation, feel free to share!