# How to get Screen Time on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

We are currently working on building an iOS app that tracks the screen-time of the user on their iOS device. I understand that apple is very restrictive and the current Screen-Time API is any accessible through Parental Settings. Is there any way we can get basic info on the screen time of the user? Even info like total screen time of the day will do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Screen Time API from Apple does not offer a report as one of their capabilities.
Answer in other question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934112/extracting-screen-time-usage-of-the-user-in-an-ios-app-maybe-with-the-screen-ti#comment121828321_68934112).

Also see WWDC video about this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934112/extracting-screen-time-usage-of-the-user-in-an-ios-app-maybe-with-the-screen-ti#comment121828321_68934112)